# Labeled Likelihood Contour Plot In R

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I have a csv file with the following values.

```
x,y
50.0,0.0
50.0,0.0
51.0,0.0
53.0,0.0
54.0,0.0
54.0,0.0
54.0,0.0
55.0,0.0
55.0,0.0
56.0,0.0
56.0,0.0
57.0,0.0
57.0,0.0
57.0,1.0
57.0,1.0
58.0,0.0
59.0,0.0
60.0,0.0
60.0,1.0
61.0,0.0
61.0,0.0
61.0,1.0
61.0,1.0
62.0,1.0
62.0,1.0
62.0,0.0
62.0,1.0
63.0,0.0
63.0,0.0
63.0,1.0
64.0,0.0
64.0,1.0
65.0,0.0
67.0,1.0
67.0,1.0
68.0,0.0
68.0,1.0
69.0,0.0
70.0,1.0
71.0,0.0
```

I can make a nice contour plot in R using the `contour()` function with the below code, but I would like to make the same thing using ggplot. Could someone show how this can be done? I also attached an image at the bottom showing what the figure looks like with the current code. [Likelihood Contour Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9ArX.png)

```
#Read in the file `xy`
x<- xy$x
y<- xy$y
#Center age
x0 <- x-mean(x)
#fit glm
xglm <- glm(y~x0,family=binomial)
# 2d likelihood
b<- summary(xglm)$coef
#intercept estimate and se
b0hat<-xglm$coef[1]; se0<- b[1,2]
#slope estimate and se
b1hat<-xglm$coef[2]; se1<- b[2,2]
#Compute the log-likelihood
fun1 <- function(bo,b1){
    sum(y*(bo+b1*x0)- log(1+exp(bo+b1*x0)))
}

lik<- NULL
#get range of values within +- 3 se for intercept
bbo<- seq(b0hat-3*se0, b0hat+3*se0 ,len=20)
#get range of values within +- 3 se for slope
bb1 <- seq(b1hat-3*se1, b1hat+3*se1,len=20)
for (bo in bbo)
{
  for (b1 in bb1){
     lik <- c(lik,fun1(bo,b1))
  }
}
#get max likelihood
maxlik <- max(lik)
#get difference
lik <- lik-maxlik
#take the exponential of the likelihood
lik<- exp(lik)

contour(bbo,bb1,matrix(lik,20,byrow=T),level=seq(.1,1,by=.2),
    xlab=expression(beta[0]),
    ylab=expression(beta[1]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
library(ggplot2)
df.lik <- setNames(expand.grid(bbo, bb1), c('x', 'y')) 
vfun1 <- Vectorize(fun1, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)

df.lik$z <- vfun1(df.lik$x,df.lik$y)       
p <- ggplot(df.lik, aes(x, y, z=z)) + stat_contour(aes(colour = ..level..))
data<- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]] 
indices <- setdiff(1:nrow(data), which(duplicated(data$level))) # distinct levels
p + 
  geom_text(aes(label=seq(0,1,by=.1), z=NULL), data=data[indices,]) +
  xlab(expression(beta[0])) +
  ylab(expression(beta[1]))
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! I learned a new command `ggplot_build`. I never new that existed. One question I have is how to I "zoom-out". I tried using the `xlim` command, but the axis got bigger and the contours stayed cut at the same axis we see above.

Comment: you could try `+ coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-1.25,0.25))`

Comment: `p + 
  geom_text(aes(label=seq(0,1,by=.1), z=NULL), data=data[indices,]) +
  xlab(expression(beta[0])) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-3.25,3.25)) +
  ylab(expression(beta[1]))` The contours are not filling the space.